# How to verify cycle count on ARM?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, arm

I am measuring cycle counts on Raspberry Pi 3b+ (ARM Cortex A53).

```
static inline uint32_t read_counter(void)
{
    uint32_t cc = 0;
    __asm__ volatile ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c9, c13, 0":"=r" (cc));  
    return cc;
}
```

This is what I do ([tutorial](https://matthewarcus.wordpress.com/2018/01/27/using-the-cycle-counter-registers-on-the-raspberry-pi-3/)):

```
uint32_t t1 = read_counter();       

volatile uint64_t n = 100000000;
while(n > 0) n--;

t1 = ccnt_read();
printf("%u\n", t1-t0);
```

When I execute the code (using `taskset` to keep the process on one CPU: `taskset 0x1 my_counter`) I get at the output: `1201120230` cycles (`1.201.120.230`). It varies, but it is always around `1.201.000.000`.

`$ time taskset 0x1 ./cycles`

How would I verify that this is OK? How do I find out my CPU frequency? Is there a better way than using the `100000000 while` loop?

Edit:
`sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu[0-3]/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq`
gives

```
1400000
1400000
1400000
1400000
```

This means expected value for the 1 second loop would be `1.400.000.000` cycles?

p.s.
I still don't understand why the above while loop is supposed to be 1 second long?

Comment: If you want to get somewhat accurate results, you better write the whole program in assembly. But I would not expect it to give you the CPU frequency because unlike some ancient architectures, modern ones do not have fixed correlation between instructions per unit of time and the clock frequency.

Comment: *"How would I verify that this is OK?"* - high res counters are usually correlated with your CPU's speed. If you read 1.2G cycles, your CPU advertises 1.4GHz, and your program takes about 1 second to run... then it looks fine.

Comment: even in asm there is no expectation for consistent results.   (even bare metal) alignment of the code and other factors can/will change the execution performance of a simple decrement and branch if not zero loop, or anything that resembles it.

Comment: running on top of an operating system.  having separate function calls to get the time, etc, just adds more room for inconsistent results (from one build to another if you change code outside this code).

Comment: you are also running from dram that is shared with the gpu, which creates more execution uncertainty times two.  Unless you are out of cache then it just goes back to alignment and branch prediction, etc creating variances in the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running:

`$ time taskset 0x1 ./cycles`

the output will give cycles and seconds:

```
Count (about) 1 second: 1201120230 cycles:

real    0m0.855s
user    0m0.854s
sys     0m0.000s
```

To check if the values "make sense", divide your cycles with the clock frequency

`1201120230 / 1400000000 = 0.857`

and compare with the time measured.

In this case it seems close, so the cycle count is OK.

Tip: since the clock frequency often varies as the CPU goes into power-save modes, it's a good idea to first set the clock to constant frequency. More info on how to do that [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/133666/126684).